# Setting ClientTemplate by Javascript

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

My Kendo Grid has a lot of columns and I want one `ClientTemplate` and possibly `EditorTemplate` for all of them.

How can I do that by Javascript?

I'm currently trying the below code which doesn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var grid = $("#myGrid").data('kendoGrid');
        for (var col in grid.columns) {
            grid.columns[col].template = "#='x'#";
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `kendo.template` for that

```
var template = kendo.template("Hello, #= firstName # #= lastName #");
```

If you want to reuse template multiple times I encourage you to make a script template like this

```
<script id="name-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
<div>
    <label>ID</label> : #: dataId #
</div>
</script>
```

and you can use it when initialize Grid with `kendo.template`

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "name",
    template: kendo.template($("#name-template").html())
  }]
});
```

[**Documentation**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template)

Comment: Because the grid already defined there, you should assign template when you define grid(before it's rendered)

Comment: I'm using MVC Wrappers, how can I do that? Isn't it possible to refresh the grid? I noticed that If I edit the Grid, it'll render the template.

Comment: Thanks Dion, but I'm using MVC Wrappers, and I prefer to instead of typing `clientTemplate` for about 40 columns, write a JS Code to do that. The reusable script suggestion in your post is great.